# VB.NET equivalent of C# interface usage as parameter

Tags: c#, vb.net, interface

EDIT 2:

Right I thought it was a problem with my syntax, so I tried to explain the situation using a simple interface. The real situation is this:

I have created an interface called IRepeatingTransaction in a module called ModGlobal:

```
Public Interface IRepeatingTransaction
    ' Definitions
End Interface
```

When I try to pass that interface as a parameter:

```
Public Sub New(R As IRepeatingTransaction)
   ' blah
End Sub
```

I get the compiler error:

```
'R' cannot expose type 'ModGlobals.IRepeatingTransaction' outside the project through class 'Transactions'
```

Comment: Should work.just on vb.net it is sub end sub

Comment: This is very easy to look up in any number of elementary references which you could find using Google.

Comment: You created a Generic Method with the generic type argument `e`. The method is parameterless, and it doesn't compile because you didn't write a body (with End Sub).

Comment: @TomW do you not think I tried that...

Comment: (ByVal e As IEnumerable)

Comment: @user574632: "ByVal e As IEnumerable" is identical to "e As IEnumerable".  'ByVal' is the default.

Comment: Maybe you will write that problem?

Comment: imports System.Collections maybe u forget this?

Comment: @TomW thanks for the thumbs down too - really constructive

Comment: Make module public.better use namespace instead and outside of module.

Comment: @qwr thanks, that works. Make a comment and I'll mark as answer

Comment: Downvoting poor questions is how StackOverflow is meant to work. At the time I last contributed, the crossed-through paragraph was the only content present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make module public or just create interface outside module.

Answer (score 2):

Use `End Sub` instead of brackets.

```
Sub MyFunc(e As IEnumerable)
    ' do something
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It's as follows.

```
Private Sub myFunc(e As IEnumarable)
    'do something
End Sub
```